# R ggplot geom_col plot propotion of one variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe :

```
df_silencer <- data.frame(
  group = c("inside_boundaries", "outside_boundaries","inside_boundaries", "outside_boundaries","inside_boundaries", "outside_boundaries","inside_boundaries", "outside_boundaries","inside_boundaries", "outside_boundaries"),
  value = c(18, 408,43,850,36,594,118,1831,1232,22765),
  cond = c('pef1a','pef1a','ppgk','ppgk','prag2','prag2','pscp1','pscp1','DHS','DHS')
)
```

I'm trying to plot only the propotion of 'inside boundaries' instead of inside_boundaries and outside_boundaries.

This give me the propotion of inside + outside on 100 %. I'm trying to plot only the inside_boundaries proportion

```
(boundaries_percentage=
    ggplot(df_silencer, 
           aes(x = cond,y = value,color=cond,fill=forcats::fct_rev(as.factor(group)))) +
    geom_col(size=0.7,alpha=0.5,width = 0.7,position = 'fill')+  
    scale_color_manual(name="Condition",breaks = c("pef1a", "ppgk", "prag2","pscp1",'DHS'),
                       values=c("#FFCC33", "#339900", "#FF3333","#3333FF","black"))+
    scale_fill_manual(name="group",breaks = c("inside_boundaries","outside_boundaries"),
                      values=c("#d6d4d4","#ffffff"))+
    scale_x_discrete(limits=c("DHS","pscp1", "ppgk", "pef1a","prag2"))+
    scale_y_continuous(labels=c("0", "25","50","75","100"))+
    theme_classic()+
    theme(text = element_text(size=6),axis.title.x = element_blank())+
    guides(color=F)+
    labs(y="% inside vs outside boundaries" )
)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df_silencer %>% 
  group_by(cond) %>% 
  mutate(pct = value/sum(value)) %>% 
  filter(group == "inside_boundaries") %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = cond,y = pct,color=cond, fill=cond)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +  
  scale_color_manual(name="Condition",breaks = c("pef1a", "ppgk", "prag2","pscp1",'DHS'),
                     values=c("#FFCC33", "#339900", "#FF3333","#3333FF","black"))+
  scale_fill_manual(name="Condition",breaks = c("pef1a", "ppgk", "prag2","pscp1",'DHS'),
                    values=c("#FFCC33", "#339900", "#FF3333","#3333FF","black"))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("DHS","pscp1", "ppgk", "pef1a","prag2"))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::label_percent(accuracy=1))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(text = element_text(size=6),axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  guides(color=F, fill=F)+
  labs(y="% inside vs outside boundaries" )
```

[image]

---

### Edit: Adding Percent Figures Over the Bar

```
df_silencer %>% 
  group_by(cond) %>% 
  mutate(pct = value/sum(value)) %>% 
  filter(group == "inside_boundaries") %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = cond,y = pct,color=cond, fill=cond)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +  
  geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%.1f%%", pct*100)), position=position_nudge(y=.0015)) + 
  scale_color_manual(name="Condition",breaks = c("pef1a", "ppgk", "prag2","pscp1",'DHS'),
                     values=c("#FFCC33", "#339900", "#FF3333","#3333FF","black"))+
  scale_fill_manual(name="Condition",breaks = c("pef1a", "ppgk", "prag2","pscp1",'DHS'),
                    values=c("#FFCC33", "#339900", "#FF3333","#3333FF","black"))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("DHS","pscp1", "ppgk", "pef1a","prag2"))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::label_percent(accuracy=1))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(text = element_text(size=6),axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  guides(color=F, fill=F)+
  labs(y="% inside vs outside boundaries" )
```

[image]

Comment: How can I add the percentage label on the plot? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean on the y-axis or do you want to add them in somewhere else.  If on the y-axis, this should do it: `scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::label_percent(accuracy=1))`

Comment: For example to print the % on the bar. Thanks

Comment: I added that to the answer.